# admin-ajax GET response bad request

Tags: php, ajax, admin-menu

I don't like to use wordpress, but I'm working on a business client website that want to use it but without the default `wp-` prefix for files and folders.To find a solution and to try satisfate this request, I've developed a script that will bulk rename patch and remove all the prefixes from wordpress files. I'm debugging the script and all works fine, the CMS installation will work fine and I can login and use all the core functions without any issue. I need to solve just one problem that I think it's related to the core files, in fact, the admin bar and the dashboard menù isn't loading properly, the icons are not loaded and the menù appears to be unstyled.
Using the console I can see that there is a problem with an ajax `GET` request and I'm not able to find a way to fix the issue. the ajax request is made to this address: 
`GET http://localhost:1507/wtest/admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp-compression-test&test=1&_ajax_nonce=321784a9f8&1543592009302 400 (Bad Request)`
that I know is a wordpress core file. I didn't modified it, but the response is always the error `400 bad request`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the core Wordpress files. Anything you do to them will break upon the first upgrade.

Comment: @JakeParis It's a client request, I've noticed that this argument of modifying wordpress cores seems to scare any developer who use this cms and this make me smile because an experienced developer doesn't care about this limitations. In my case, I need only to fix this small issue to make the dashboard menu styled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem without using a plugin, (in fact my [script](https://github.com/ziobru/wp-deprefix) run before the wordpress is installed) after some hours of debug, I've found where is the problem. I was removing the wp- prefix from all files,that It's useful for only one action inside the `admin-ajax.php` file that is `wp-compression-test` action, that is made using a `GET` request. My script was modifying the name and the error was because the passed action was only `compression-test` instead of `wp-compression-test`. 
I've made a patch for this, and I was able to get the wordpress installation working without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jumping through backward hoops and editing the WordPress core (You should never do this!) Just install the [Hide My WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-my-wp/).

Comment: I know about plugins that are hiding the wp admin folder, furthermore the scope isn't related to the wp-admin folder hiding, the client didn't requested this, he want a totally hacked wordpress version, this is why I've made the script. As i wrote in the question, I have no problem with the installation and contents creation, but only with the styles of the admin menu bar/dashboard.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would the client want this?

Comment: I agree with @Swen. Maybe this is a question of client-education.

Comment: @Swen It's a business website for a great company.